# How to replace WIFI antenna of Dell Inspiron 7548?

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-inspiron, antenna

I need to replace the WIFI antenna + cable of my Dell Inspiron 7548. The unit [appears to look like this](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000837463298.html). But is that part attached to the LCD screen or part of it? How exactly would I replace that part?

I understand how to disassemble the Dell 7548 display unit completely. I have found many videos about that and the [DELL service manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-7548-laptop_service%20manual_en-us.pdf) tells me how to detach the whole video screen. But no word of how to replace the antenna. Is that part of the display and how would I open the LCD screen unit?

Just to make it clear: I am **NOT talking about the WIFI card**, I need to replace the part with the white and black cable.

So any hint of how to replace the antenna + cable is much appreciated. That is how the spare part looks like:

[image: 7548 antenna spare part]

---

Edit: Closest screen tutorial at YT I have found so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0qFkz6zHD8&t=330s

Comment: You need to disassemble the lid/screen, find the antenna and replace it when you take apart the lid.   https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Dell+Inspiron+15-7548+Display+Replacement/125130

Comment: Thanks, I see. It is part of the display cover. Any idea what kind of "adhesive" I would need to glue it back in? I have found some "mobile screen adhesive", but not sure if i could use that. Need to sleep it over if that repair is worth the risk, or an external card is the better approach.

Comment: Any reasonable adhesive should work (the document does not say).  It is a tricky procedure (done this on an IBM Laptop) so take that into account. Maybe let a local repair shop replace the antenna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antenna is buried inside the lid.  See:

[Dell Inspiron lid disassembly](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Dell+Inspiron+15-7548+Display+Replacement/125130)

It is a fairly tricky repair. (I have done this on an IBM ThinkPad).

If you decide to repair, you should be able to use the correct replacement cable (connectors for the card) and connect to the wires in the lid. Trim wires to fit and solder carefully.

You could inexpensively add a USB Wireless Card and disable the built in card in Device Manager.

This is probably the best approach here.

Comment: Got it, the problem is that one of these tiny connectors for the internal WIFI card is gone. I will try a workaround first and see if I can get a new cable and solder it on the antenna cable.

Comment: That could work. Take care soldering as the wires are delicate. The Dell replacement cable should have the correct connector to the card and solder the cable to the existing wire in the display. Trim to fit.