# What is the name of this connector (2x) of an internal Laptop WIFI card? (Dell Inspiron 7548)

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, dell-inspiron, connector

What is the name of this connector on top of my internal WIFI card (it looks like a very tiny version of a coaxial connector)? The ones on top labelled WLAN. It goes to the WIFI antenna.

I need to buy that connector or a cable with such a connector already attached/mounted. What is the correct name for that?

1. Is that 2x MHF IV (I-PEX)?
2. Or SMT Mini-Coax?

[image: DELL WIFI card]

---

Related to: [How to replace WIFI antenna of Dell Inspiron 7548?](https://superuser.com/q/1642615/72397)

Comment: The connectors are not necessarily standard. I think you will see what you need here.  The connectors are for a single wire, not coax.   https://www.banggood.com/5Pcs-IPEX-or-Welding-2_4G-3dBi-Copper-Tube-Antenna-Internal-WIFI-Aerial-Omnidirectional-Built-in-Antenna-with-Sleeve-for-Laptop-p-1532378.html?cur_warehouse=CN&ID=6266230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is I-PEX MHF4 (ring outside diameter 1.5 mm).
Other common wifi connector is MHF1/u.FL (ring outside diameter 2 mm).

[image]